# Docker on Raspberry pi - Problem with pipenv

Tags: python, linux, docker, raspberry-pi

I have problem when i try install my app on RaspberryPi. On Windows (Docker Desktop) all work but when i try do this on RPi (Debian) i have error:

```
#0 10.23 Creating a virtualenv for this project...
#0 10.24 Pipfile: /app/Pipfile
#0 10.51 Using /usr/local/bin/python3.8 (3.8.9) to create virtualenv...
#0 20.57 created virtual environment CPython3.8.9.final.0-32 in 6531ms
#0 20.57   creator CPython3Posix(dest=/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
#0 20.57   seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/root/.local/share/virtualenv)
#0 20.57     added seed packages: pip==23.1.2, setuptools==67.7.2, wheel==0.40.0
#0 20.57   activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
#0 20.57
#0 20.61 ✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
#0 21.34 Virtualenv location: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q
#0 21.64 Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (456221)...
#0 154.1 An error occurred while installing attrdict==2.0.1 --hash=sha256:35c90698b55c683946091177177a9e9c0713a0860f0e049febd72649ccd77b70 --hash=sha256:9432e3498c74ff7e1b20b3d93b45d766b71cbffa90923496f82c4ae38b92be34! Will try again.
#0 154.1 An error occurred while installing bidict==0.22.1 ; python_version >= '3.7' --hash=sha256:1e0f7f74e4860e6d0943a05d4134c63a2fad86f3d4732fb265bd79e4e856d81d --hash=sha256:6ef212238eb884b664f28da76f33f1d28b260f665fc737b413b287d5487d1e7b! Will try again.
#0 154.1 An error occurred while installing certifi==2020.12.5 --hash=sha256:1a4995114262bffbc2413b159f2a1a480c969de6e6eb13ee966d470af86af59c --hash=sha256:719a74fb9e33b9bd44cc7f3a8d94bc35e4049deebe19ba7d8e108280cfd59830! Will try again.
#0 154.1 An error occurred while installing cffi==1.14.5 --hash=sha256:005a36f41773e148deac64b08f233873a4d0c18b053d37da83f6af4d9087b813 --hash=sha256:04c468b622ed31d408fea2346bec5bbffba2cc44226302a0de1ade9f5ea3d373 --hash=sha256:06d7cd1abac2ffd92e65c0609661866709b4b2d82dd15f611e602b9b188b0b69 --hash=sha256:06db6321b7a68b2bd6df96d08a5adadc1fa0e8f419226e25b2a5fbf6ccc7350f --hash=sha256:0857f0ae312d855239a55c81ef453ee8fd24136eaba8e87a2eceba644c0d4c06 --hash=sha256:0f861a89e0043afec2a51fd177a567005847973be86f709bbb044d7f42fc4e05 --hash=sha256:1071534bbbf8cbb31b498d5d9db0f274f2f7a865adca4ae429e147ba40f73dea --hash=sha256:158d0d15119b4b7ff6b926536763dc0714313aa59e320ddf787502c70c4d4bee --hash=sha256:1bf1ac1984eaa7675ca8d5745a8cb87ef7abecb5592178406e55858d411eadc0 --hash=sha256:1f436816fc868b098b0d63b8920de7d208c90a67212546d02f84fe78a9c26396 --hash=sha256:24a570cd11895b60829e941f2613a4f79df1a27344cbbb82164ef2e0116f09c7 --hash=sha256:24ec4ff2c5c0c8f9c6b87d5bb53555bf267e1e6f70e52e5a9740d32861d36b6f --hash=sha256:2894f2df484ff56d717bead0a5c2abb6b9d2bf26d6960c4604d5c48bbc30ee73 --hash=sha256:29314480e958fd8aab22e4a58b355b629c59bf5f2ac2492b61e3dc06d8c7a315 --hash=sha256:293e7ea41280cb28c6fcaaa0b1aa1f533b8ce060b9e701d78511e1e6c4a1de76 --hash=sha256:34eff4b97f3d982fb93e2831e6750127d1355a923ebaeeb565407b3d2f8d41a1 --hash=sha256:35f27e6eb43380fa080dccf676dece30bef72e4a67617ffda586641cd4508d49 --hash=sha256:3c3f39fa737542161d8b0d680df2ec249334cd70a8f420f71c9304bd83c3cbed --hash=sha256:3d3dd4c9e559eb172ecf00a2a7517e97d1e96de2a5e610bd9b68cea3925b4892 --hash=sha256:43e0b9d9e2c9e5d152946b9c5fe062c151614b262fda2e7b201204de0b99e482 --hash=sha256:48e1c69bbacfc3d932221851b39d49e81567a4d4aac3b21258d9c24578280058 --hash=sha256:51182f8927c5af975fece87b1b369f722c570fe169f9880764b1ee3bca8347b5 --hash=sha256:58e3f59d583d413809d60779492342801d6e82fefb89c86a38e040c16883be53 --hash=sha256:5de7970188bb46b7bf9858eb6890aad302577a5f6f75091fd7cdd3ef13ef3045 --hash=sha256:65fa59693c62cf06e45ddbb822165394a288edce9e276647f0046e1ec26920f3 --hash=sha256:681d07b0d1e3c462dd15585ef5e33cb021321588bebd910124ef4f4fb71aef55 --hash=sha256:69e395c24fc60aad6bb4fa7e583698ea6cc684648e1ffb7fe85e3c1ca131a7d5 --hash=sha256:6c97d7350133666fbb5cf4abdc1178c812cb205dc6f41d174a7b0f18fb93337e --hash=sha256:6e4714cc64f474e4d6e37cfff31a814b509a35cb17de4fb1999907575684479c --hash=sha256:72d8d3ef52c208ee1c7b2e341f7d71c6fd3157138abf1a95166e6165dd5d4369 --hash=sha256:8ae6299f6c68de06f136f1f9e69458eae58f1dacf10af5c17353eae03aa0d827 --hash=sha256:8b198cec6c72df5289c05b05b8b0969819783f9418e0409865dac47288d2a053 --hash=sha256:99cd03ae7988a93dd00bcd9d0b75e1f6c426063d6f03d2f90b89e29b25b82dfa --hash=sha256:9cf8022fb8d07a97c178b02327b284521c7708d7c71a9c9c355c178ac4bbd3d4 --hash=sha256:9de2e279153a443c656f2defd67769e6d1e4163952b3c622dcea5b08a6405322 --hash=sha256:9e93e79c2551ff263400e1e4be085a1210e12073a31c2011dbbda14bda0c6132 --hash=sha256:9ff227395193126d82e60319a673a037d5de84633f11279e336f9c0f189ecc62 --hash=sha256:a465da611f6fa124963b91bf432d960a555563efe4ed1cc403ba5077b15370aa --hash=sha256:ad17025d226ee5beec591b52800c11680fca3df50b8b29fe51d882576e039ee0 --hash=sha256:afb29c1ba2e5a3736f1c301d9d0abe3ec8b86957d04ddfa9d7a6a42b9367e396 --hash=sha256:b85eb46a81787c50650f2392b9b4ef23e1f126313b9e0e9013b35c15e4288e2e --hash=sha256:bb89f306e5da99f4d922728ddcd6f7fcebb3241fc40edebcb7284d7514741991 --hash=sha256:cbde590d4faaa07c72bf979734738f328d239913ba3e043b1e98fe9a39f8b2b6 --hash=sha256:cc5a8e069b9ebfa22e26d0e6b97d6f9781302fe7f4f2b8776c3e1daea35f1adc --hash=sha256:cd2868886d547469123fadc46eac7ea5253ea7fcb139f12e1dfc2bbd406427d1 --hash=sha256:d42b11d692e11b6634f7613ad8df5d6d5f8875f5d48939520d351007b3c13406 --hash=sha256:df5052c5d867c1ea0b311fb7c3cd28b19df469c056f7fdcfe88c7473aa63e333 --hash=sha256:f2d45f97ab6bb54753eab54fffe75aaf3de4ff2341c9daee1987ee1837636f1d --hash=sha256:fd78e5fee591709f32ef6edb9a015b4aa1a5022598e36227500c8f4e02328d9c! Will try again.
#0 154.1 An error occurred while installing chardet==4.0.0 ; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4' --hash=sha256:0d6f53a15db4120f2b08c94f11e7d93d2c911ee118b6b30a04ec3ee8310179fa --hash=sha256:f864054d66fd9118f2e67044ac8981a54775ec5b67aed0441892edb553d21da5! Will try again.
#0 154.1 An error occurred while installing click==7.1.2 ; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4' --hash=sha256:d2b5255c7c6349bc1bd1e59e08cd12acbbd63ce649f2588755783aa94dfb6b1a --hash=sha256:dacca89f4bfadd5de3d7489b7c8a566eee0d3676333fbb50030263894c38c0dc! Will try again.
#0 154.1 An error occurred while installing crcmod==1.7 --hash=sha256:50586ab48981f11e5b117523d97bb70864a2a1af246cf6e4f5c4a21ef4611cd1 --hash=sha256:69a2e5c6c36d0f096a7beb4cd34e5f882ec5fd232efb710cdb85d4ff196bd52e --hash=sha256:737fb308fa2ce9aed2e29075f0d5980d4a89bfbec48a368c607c5c63b3efb90e --hash=sha256:dc7051a0db5f2bd48665a990d3ec1cc305a466a77358ca4492826f41f283601e! Will try again.
#0 154.1 An error occurred while installing cryptography==3.4.7 ; python_version >= '3.6' --hash=sha256:0f1212a66329c80d68aeeb39b8a16d54ef57071bf22ff4e521657b27372e327d --hash=sha256:1e056c28420c072c5e3cb36e2b23ee55e260cb04eee08f702e0edfec3fb51959 --hash=sha256:240f5c21aef0b73f40bb9f78d2caff73186700bf1bc6b94285699aff98cc16c6 --
...
...
...
...
...
'sha256:6f80a9c9a9af0e4bd5080cc0955ce70274c28e9b931ad7e0fb07021afcd32af6', 'sha256:88ab245ed2c96265441ed2818977be28c840cfa5204ba167425d6c26eb67b7e7', 'sha256:788d1772fb8dcd12091ca82809eef504ce0f2c423e45284bc351b872966ff554', 'sha256:f7f994a53c0e6b44a2966fd6bfc53e37d34b7dca34e75b6be295de6db598255e', 'sha256:f6fd3c88ea4b170d13527e93be1945e69facd917661d3725a63470eb683fbffe', 'sha256:536c86ec81ca89291d533ff41a3a05f9e4e88e01906dcee0751fc7082f3e8d6c', 'sha256:1e885dacb167077df15af2f9ccdacbd7f5dd0d538a6d74b94074f2cefc7bb589'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=sqlalchemy, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===2.0.15, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=sqlalchemy==2.0.15)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='typing-extensions', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='typing-extensions', version='==4.6.3', req=Requirement.parse('typing-extensions==4.6.3; python_version >= "3.7"'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=typing-extensions, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '3.7', vcs=None, specifier===4.6.3, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=typing-extensions==4.6.3)>), markers='python_version >= "3.7"', _specifiers='==4.6.3', index=None, editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:88a4153d8505aabbb4e13aacb7c486c2b4a33ca3b3f807914a9b4c844c471c26', 'sha256:d91d5919357fe7f681a9f2b5b4cb2a5f1ef0a1e9f59c4d8ff0d3491e05c0ffd5'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=typing-extensions, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '3.7', vcs=None, specifier===4.6.3, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=typing-extensions==4.6.3)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='urllib3', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='urllib3', version='==1.26.4', req=Requirement.parse('urllib3==1.26.4'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=urllib3, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===1.26.4, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=urllib3==1.26.4)>), markers=None, _specifiers='==1.26.4', index='pypi', editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:2f4da4594db7e1e110a944bb1b551fdf4e6c136ad42e4234131391e21eb5b0df', 'sha256:e7b021f7241115872f92f43c6508082facffbd1c048e3c6e2bb9c2a157e28937'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=urllib3, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===1.26.4, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=urllib3==1.26.4)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='websocket-client', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='websocket-client', version='==0.59', req=Requirement.parse('websocket-client==0.59'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=websocket-client, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===0.59, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=websocket-client==0.59)>), markers=None, _specifiers='==0.59', index='pypi', editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:2e50d26ca593f70aba7b13a489435ef88b8fc3b5c5643c1ce8808ff9b40f0b32', 'sha256:d376bd60eace9d437ab6d7ee16f4ab4e821c9dae591e1b783c58ebd8aaf80c5c'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=websocket-client, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===0.59, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=websocket-client==0.59)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='werkzeug', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='werkzeug', version='==1.0.1', req=Requirement.parse('werkzeug==1.0.1; python_version >= "2.7" and python_version not in "3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4"'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=werkzeug, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4', vcs=None, specifier===1.0.1, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=werkzeug==1.0.1)>), markers='python_version >= "2.7" and python_version not in "3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4"', _specifiers='==1.0.1', index=None, editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:6c80b1e5ad3665290ea39320b91e1be1e0d5f60652b964a3070216de83d2e47c', 'sha256:2de2a5db0baeae7b2d2664949077c2ac63fbd16d98da0ff71837f7d1dea3fd43'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=werkzeug, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4', vcs=None, specifier===1.0.1, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=werkzeug==1.0.1)>, _ireq=None)]
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pipenv install --ignore-pipfile" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Docker file:

```
FROM python:3.8.9

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER 1
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8

WORKDIR /app

# Copy pipenv files
COPY Pipfile /app/

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential python-dev \
    libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev libev4 libev-dev

# Update pip and install pipenv
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv

# Copy the project
COPY . /app/

# Build the project
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system

# Run the project
CMD sleep infinity
```

- RUN pipenv install --ignore-pipfile
- Change pipenv to poetry (Problem with cryptography and rustup)

Comment: Might be that you need to build the wheel yourself. Try commeting out depedencies from your lock file until it works, then you know which ones makes problems.

Comment: @TheFool I tried to install pipenv with option --skip-lock but still no work

Comment: skip lock still ready your dependencies from the pipfile.  My suggestion doesn't make a lot of sense, though. As I see now that its actually failing on all the packages. Can you provide  the pipfile so someone can try to reproduce this?

Comment: maybe you can also see if you can increase the verbosity of pipenv logs. Becuase right now its not telling alot of useful things.

Comment: hm, please also show your project tree and .dockerignore. I get the feeling that it may be because you copy your local venv folder into the container. The way venv works is that its tightly coupled with the host system. So moving it from your local machine into the container is probably causing some problems. If you have the venv folder in your project, that is.